# In a coordinate change $\frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu } = \frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \tilde x^\lambda}$?

Tags: tensor-calculus

So I was  verifying wether $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu$ is a scalar. To do this I used the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x^\nu}, \qquad \frac{\partial }{\partial x_\mu} = \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\lambda}.  $$

Bringing them together
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_\mu} = \left( \frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x^\nu}\right) \left(  \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\lambda}\right) = 
\frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu \partial \tilde x^\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\lambda} +
 \frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu } \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^\nu} \frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\lambda}.$$
The first term in the right hand side (RHS) must be zero (right?), and we can get it by using the chain rule and changing the derivative $x_\mu$ by one with respect to some $\tilde x_\kappa$, this would give a Kronecker delta which derived must be zero. Now the second term in the RHS, should be
$$ \delta^\nu_\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^\nu} \frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\lambda} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde x^\nu} \frac{\partial }{\partial \tilde x_\nu},$$
but this would imply that 
$$\frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu } = \delta^\nu_\lambda \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{\partial x_\mu } = \frac{\partial  x^\mu }{\partial \tilde x^\lambda}.$$

My  question is: is this last equation correct? And could you give a proof?

So far I have done the same thing using $\partial_\mu T^\mu = \partial^\mu T_\mu$, and the LHS of the equation is simple, but in the RHS again the  derivatives with respect to $x_\mu$ makes the problem equation necessary:

$$ \frac{\partial }{ \partial x_\mu} T_\mu = \left( \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{ \partial x_\mu} \frac{\partial }{ \partial \tilde x_\lambda}  \right) \left( \frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{ \partial x^\mu} \tilde T_\nu  \right) =  
\underbrace{ \frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{ \partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial^2 \tilde x^\nu }{ \partial \tilde x_\lambda \partial x^\mu} \tilde T_\nu }_{=0}
+
\frac{\partial \tilde x_\lambda }{ \partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial \tilde x^\nu }{ \partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial }{ \partial \tilde  x_\lambda }  \tilde T_\nu $$
and
$$\frac{\partial }{ \partial x_\mu} T_\mu = \frac{\partial }{ \partial \tilde x_\nu} \tilde T_\nu. $$

I guess that this does not constitute a proof. So again my question:

Is the identity true in general? Could you give a proof?

Thank you!

Comment: Tip: Avoid using coordinates $x_{\mu}$ with lower indices, as their transformation properties in GR becomes obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial^\mu$ is not $\partial/\partial x_\lambda$.  There is no such thing as $x_\lambda$. Instead $\partial^\mu \equiv  g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$. In curvilinear coordintes $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu$ is not a scalar. The useful combination is the Laplacian acting on scalars which is
$$
\nabla^2 \varphi= \frac 1{\sqrt g}\partial_\mu (\sqrt{g} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu\varphi).
$$

Comment: Actually $\partial x^a / \partial x^b \neq \delta^a_b  $ in general right?, and that crossed term I said to be zero is neither, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your identity is false. Here is a simple counter example in 2D switching between cartesian and polar coordinates: $(x^1,x^2)=(x,y)$ and $(\tilde{x}^1,\tilde{x}^2)=(r,\theta)$.

A simple calculation yields
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^1}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}  =  \frac{y}{r},
$$
as well as
$$
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \tilde{x}^2} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}  =  - y .
$$
Clearly we have $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}^1}{\partial x^2} \neq \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}$, which contradicts your proposed relation.